# How to make my icosphere inflate in a heart shape?

Tags: cloth-simulation, vertex-groups, soft-body, shrinkwrap

I am trying to create a soft body/ cloth simulation where the eyeballs inflate and pop out of the eye socket and form into a heart shape.

I tried quite some different approaches now but none worked out so far.

At first I shaped a heart from a cube and subdivided the faces so it would create a smooth mesh which I added soft body physics to. Then I applied a force field but the effect would not create a realistic round eyeball in the first frames like in this tutorial:
[How to create a soft body in blender 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxcR_s3_VMs&t=648s)

Next I tried to use cloth physics to let the heart shaped cube inflate itself but the shape got lost in the process.

Then I tried this tutorial: [Make ANYTHING Inflated | Blender3D Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxcR_s3_VMs)

I separated the edges of the initial heart form:

[image]

I snapped it to the icosphere's surface, beveled and shrink-wrapped it to the surface of the icosphere:

[image]

As this did not work at all I took the knife tool and splitted the faces by hand. Then I beveled the edges and assigned a vertex group to it like in the tutorial above:

[image]

This was the best result so far but the inflation happens less on the heart shaped part:

[image]

Is there anyone that tried this before or has an idea how to create the desired result?
Please let me know if you need further information or screenshots/ .blend file.
Really hoping on somebody's expertise as I am quite a beginner with blender.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Hello do you have 2 pictures of the before and after of the effect you want?

Comment: +1 moonboots :) ... I see I misunderstood your Q, so my A seems to be wrong ... mockup of desired result is appreciated.

Comment: Usually you'll want to ask yourself "what is this geometry supposed to do?", and then imagine a **topology** that works best for enabling that. Whether it's morphing, armature-driven deformation, physics, or just being a still mesh. Then, think of how to achieve that shape without a higher poly count than is necessary.

Answer (score 14):

This approach works backwards.. starts with a heart model, and normalizes it to a sphere. This could be done with a *Cast* modifier, Shape-Keys..but if you roll-your-own with Geometry nodes, you perhaps leave yourself with more options, including some not shown here.. other ways of changing eye-shape.. blinking, etc.

Heart-Eye GN:

[image]

Example animation:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I really depend on your final animation goal ...

... here just an Icosphere (16/8) with two shape keys. Create a *Basis* Key and *Key1* and in edit mode select midlle loop, move it down and do other small adjustments to reshape sphere into a heart.

[image]

[image]

Animate *Value* of shape key of *Key1* ...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Create this shape:

[image]

Give it a *Cloth* simulation, disable *Gravity* and enable *Pressure* (here -6):

[image]

Apply the *Cloth* modifier, give 2 shapekeys to your object, select the second shapekey, turn it to sphere with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>:

[image]

Move the second shapekey to top, keyframe the value of this second shapekey in order to create this kind of animation:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, the first answer to actually match: 'soft body'

Comment: It's just variation around the shapekey solution    ;)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Forget about turning the sphere into a heart.  Why?  Because unless you use infinite vertices, you need to care a little bit about topology, and spheres are topologically simple while hearts are topologically complex.  Turn the heart into a sphere instead.

1. Make a heart.  Give it some combination of good topo and high vertex density.  More of one or more of the other, whatever you feel like.

[image]

2. Duplicate the heart.  Give it a cast modifier (cast to sphere, defaults) on factor 1.0.  Tune the shape of the heart so that your topo doesn't give you an ugly sphere.

[image]

3. Convert both to mesh.  Join the sphere to the heart as a shape.  Or, vice versa.

[image]